# Returning an integer with the first row index that contains a string in a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In a `Pandas DataFrame`, I'm trying to return the integer that corresponds to the row number of the first row that contains a string in a particular column. In the `DataFrame` below, if I am looking for X I would want to return 3, which is the row index where X is located. Thanks!

```
  A B C D
0 N D O P
1 J I T V
2 V N T E
3 X W T I
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.stack()` `.isin` and `idxmax()`

```
df.stack().isin(['T']).idxmax()

out: (1, 'C')

#or [0] if you only want the integer index.

df.stack().isin(['T']).idxmax()
out: 1

df.stack().isin(['X']).idxmax()[0]
out: 3
```

---

or a more succinct answer by `@Shubham Sharma`

```
df.eq('X').any(1).idxmax()
3
```